# TWebBrowser Can Undo or Redo

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

With a TWebBrower how can you get the undo or redo state (CanUndo, Can Redo)?

This always is false?

```
  Undo1.Enabled := HTMLDocument2Ifc.queryCommandValue( 'Undo' );
  Redo1.Enabled := HTMLDocument2Ifc.queryCommandValue( 'Redo' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for might be [queryCommandEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. I guess Undo and Redo commands will only be enabled when the browser is in [edit mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).